# Scrapy Output to MySql on one line

Tags: scrapy, mysql-python, scrapy-pipeline

I am having trouble getting scrapy to output results on multiple lines in my database. I know how to get it to loop when i export to a json file but since i am a noob with scrapy i followed some tutorials on the syntax for exporting to a database but it puts the returned data all on one line.
Here is my code for the spider

```
import scrapy


from ..items import SandboxItem
class IndigoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Indigo'
    start_urls = ['https://www.chapters.indigo.ca/en-ca/books/?link-usage=Header%3A%20books&mc=Book&lu=Main']


def parse(self, response):
    items = SandboxItem()
    Product_Name= str(response.css('.product-list__product-title-link--grid::text').getall()),
    Product_Author= str(response.css('.product-list__contributor::text').getall()),
    Product_Price= str(response.css('.product-list__price--orange::text').getall()),
    Product_Image=  str(response.css('.product-image--lazy::attr(src)').getall())

    items['Product_Name'] = Product_Name
    items['Product_Author'] = Product_Author
    items['Product_Price'] = Product_Price
    items['Product_Image'] = Product_Image

    yield items
```

Here is my code for my pipeline

```
import mysql.connector

class SandboxPipeline(object):


    def __init__(self):
        self.create_connection()
        self.create_table()
        # pass

    def create_connection(self):
        self.conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            host='localhost',  
            user='root',
            passwd='test123',
            database='python',
            auth_plugin='mysql_native_password'
        )
        self.curr = self.conn.cursor()

    def create_table(self):
        self.curr.execute(""" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS indigo""")
        self.curr.execute(""" Create table indigo(
        Product_Name text,
        Product_Author text,
        Product_Price text,
        Product_Image text
        )""")

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.store_db(item)
        #     print("pipelinexds:" + str(item['Product_Name']))
        #     print(str(item['Product_Name']))
        return item

    #
    def store_db(self, item):
        self.curr.execute("""Insert Into indigo values (%s,%s,%s,%s)""",
                          ((item['Product_Name'][0]),
                           (item['Product_Author'][0]),
                           (item['Product_Price'][0]),
                           (item['Product_Image'][0]),
                           )
                          )
        self.conn.commit()
```

[Database output looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sj8V6.png)
.

Comment: it is putting all yielded items in one row of db?

Comment: Yeah it concatenates the scraped data all in one row

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your `item` containing multiple items indeed.
So you need to include `for` loop somewhere to change architecture of the program.

I'd suggest to use something like:

```
for i in len(Product_Name):
    yield  {
        'Product_Name': Product_Name[i],
        'Product_Author': Product_Author[i],
        'Product_Price': Product_Price[i],
        'Product_Image': Product_Image[i]
    }
```

So item will contain single value. This should be processed properly.

```
def parse(self, response):
    items = SandboxItem()
    Product_Name= str(response.css('.product-list__product-title-link--grid::text').getall()),
    Product_Author= str(response.css('.product-list__contributor::text').getall()),
    Product_Price= str(response.css('.product-list__price--orange::text').getall()),
    Product_Image=  str(response.css('.product-image--lazy::attr(src)').getall())

    for i in len(Product_Name):
        yield  {
            'Product_Name': Product_Name[i],
            'Product_Author': Product_Author[i],
            'Product_Price': Product_Price[i],
            'Product_Image': Product_Image[i]
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Michael, can you please let me know where I should put that loop? Should it be in the spider where my css code is or somewhere else ? Thanks

Comment: Hey Michael sorry for the delayed response but it looks like this causes no data to flow to the database.